# Curl request in PowerShell with TLS certificates

Tags: windows, docker, powershell, ssl, curl

I want to access my docker daemon from my host machine (Windows) through Windows powershell/cmd. I have certificates and everything is ready, but I don't know and I cannot find what is the Curl request in PowerShell to add my certificates to the request. This is the request in Linux, what is it converted in PowerShell, because if I try it in PowerShell I get errors for `--cert`?

```
curl https://192.168.99.102:2376/images/json --cert cert.pem --key key.pem --cacert ca.pem
```

I want to access my docker daemon from my host machine (Windows) through windows powershell/cmd.

Comment: Windows 10 / Windows Server 2019 and above now come with `curl.exe`  (and `tar.exe`), so you can use existing `curl` commands (small adjustments for PowerShell's syntax may be needed) - just make sure you specify the executable as `curl.exe`, not just `curl`, because the latter is a built-in _alias_ for the `Invoke-WebRequest` cmdlet in Windows PowerShell.

Comment: Thanks,i get this error now,i'm in the directory of where the certificates are.

curl: (58) schannel: Failed to import cert file cert.pem, last error is 0x80092002

Comment: The error means "An error occurred during encode or decode operation." - https://www.hresult.info/FACILITY_SSPI/0x80092002